# Object on the flaps?

Tags: boeing

I was on a intercontinental flight to the US and noticed this object shaking with the wind and moving as the flaps change position. Is this normal? I have never seen this before. Is it safe to travel with this kind of item on the trailing edge?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a rubber gasket came off the track fairing, nothing too critical. I'm pretty sure we've had this question before, but your phrasing makes this one stand out :) (edited out in less than 5 min)

Comment: Is that an inter-flap seal that has become dislodged? It that's the case, it's not unsafe, but maintenance would need to straighten it up.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Then.. is it ok to take off with that problem? Or the plane shouldn’t have departured till it was fixed? I noticed the cable going out before departure

Comment: What was the aircraft type? I cannot tell from the pictures (though I'm sure some of our regulars can) and it would help get an accurate answer. You can usually find it on your ticket.

Comment: It is a Boeing -767-300